# ResumableJs: Parallel uploading not working

Tags: javascript, resumablejs

I want to upload files simultaneously.

This is my Resumable config.

```
 this.resumable = new Resumable({
            target: endpoint,
            simultaneousUploads: 4,
            maxFiles: 4,
            chunkSize:1*1024*1024,
            testChunks:false,
        });
```

and I called upload on the fileAdded event.

```
this.resumable.on('fileAdded', (file) => {
            this.resumable.upload();
});
```

This setup is uploading only a single file in time. What am I doing wrong? Documentation is not helpful at all...

Answer (score 0):

The actual uploading for ResumableJS starts with this line of code.

```
this.resumable.upload();
```

Hence, from what you have showed, uploading starts as soon as a single file is added.

You will have to **remove the line** from the `'fileAdded'` closure. And **start the upload separately** triggered by a form submission (or however you please).